# Laravel 5.0 php artisan tinker throwing an error on homestead with php7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, homestead, php-7

I'm using Laravel 5.0 and homestead 0.4.0 wich is shipped with php 7,
so when I use php artisan tinker I get this error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwLYY.jpg)

How can I fix this or should I downgrade my php version and if so wouldn't be any conflict with composer or any other tool in my homestead or laravel?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that one of the libraries your application is using - **PhpParser** - is not compatible with PHP7. It defines a class called **String** which is a reserved keyword in version 7.

You need to either downgrade to **PHP5** or check if it's possible to upgrade your dependencies so that used PhpParser library is compatible with PHP7. Version 2.x of PhpParser should be compatible.

If you're including the package directly in your **composer.json** try to upgrade version there.

If not, you can see which of your dependencies requires **PhpParser** by calling

```
composer depends nikic/php-parser
```

See if you are able to upgrade versions of packages it lists.

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate,I've tried to upgrade the library to v 2.* but it fails even when I deleted composer.lock, so I'm downloading an older version of homestead with php 5.

Comment: What is failing when you're trying to upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by installing an older version of homestead v0.3.3 wich is shipped with php 5.6 so here is all you need to download it:

```
$vagrant box add laravel/homestead --box-version 0.3.3
```

and then download an older version of [Homestead](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/releases) installer from git, I'm using v2.1.8 it works fine: